# Snakemake. Set of experiments to be run sequentially on different resources

Tags: python, snakemake

Excuse the length of the question - the problem is a bit complex and I think it is interesting, so I wanted to illustrate it clearly and in full detail, providing working code that can be tested, including my (not very fruitful) attempts.

### The problem

Assume that I have a set of experiments to do on different Virtual Machines with different characteristics, for example, to determine the runtime of different workloads. In each machine there is a set of experiments depending on other parameters, which vary the workload, as for example the name of the application to run, the size of the problem to solve, etc.

To simplify, assume only the following parameters that define each experiment:

1. The type of the virtual machine (eg: small, medium, large)
2. The name of the application to run (eg: eratostenes, fibonacci)
3. The size of the problem to solve (eg: 100, 500, 1000)

With these parameters, the number of experiments to run is 3 x 2 x 3 = 18

As a result I want 18 files, each one containing different statistics about the experiment. The names of the files will use the pattern `VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data` as for example *"VM_small_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data"* and so on.

### Naive approach

So far, so good. I can easily write a Snakefile that perform these tasks:

```py
vm_types = ["small", "medium", "large"]
applications = ["eratostenes", "fibonacci"]
sizes = [100, 500, 1000]
all_files = expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", type=vm_types, app_name=applications, size=sizes)

def perform_experiment(params):
    print("Faking experiment with params", params)
    with open("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data".format(**params), "w") as f:
        f.write("Dummy data")

rule all:
    input: all_files

rule perform_experiment:
    output: "VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data"
    run:
        perform_experiment(wildcards)
```

In fact the problem is slightly more complex, because the VMs required for the experiments have to be created and started before the experiment can take place. So I need to add extra tasks for starting up the virtual machine, and include dependencies among tasks. For example:

```py
vm_types = ["small", "medium", "large"]
applications = ["eratostenes", "fibonacci"]
sizes = [100, 500, 1000]
all_files = expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", type=vm_types, app_name=applications, size=sizes)

def perform_experiment(params):
    print("Faking experiment with params", params)
    with open("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data".format(**params), "w") as f:
        f.write("Dummy data")

def start_vm(t):
    print("Starting VM", t)

rule all:
    input: all_files

rule perform_experiment:
    input: "VM_{type}_start.done"
    output: "VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data"
    run:
        perform_experiment(wildcards)

rule start_vm:
    output: touch("VM_{type}_start.done")
    run:
        start_vm(wildcards.type)
```

### The real problem

The problem is that the DAG of this workflow has no dependencies between VMs, so all experiments could be done in parallel, in principle. Even if I enforce `--jobs 1` to avoid parallelism, since the experiments are independent, snakemake can choose to start by any experiment in any of the VM types, and then perform the next experiment in a different VM type, etc.

This is not what I want. Asssume that I don't have the resources to run several VM in parallel, so I want to perform the tests in each VM sequentially. In addition, starting up and shutting down a machine takes time, so I want to leverage the fact that one VM is started to perform all required experiments inside that machine. That is:

```
For each virtual machine type:
  - Set up that vm
  - Perform all experiments that must be done in that virtual machine
  - Stop that virtual machine
```

How would be the best way to accomplish this?

### My attempt

I thought about introducing additional tasks to stop the VM, which should also produce a file like *"VM_small_stop.done"*, and initiate the start-up of a new VM type depending on the stopping of the previous one. In addition, the "stop_vm" task can only be run after all experiments in that VM are done, so I need to introduce dependencies between "stop_vm" and "perform_experiment".

Also, I need to "manually" delete the file VM_{type}_start.done when a machine is stopped, as part of the code which stops it (there is way to specify as `output` the *absence* of a file so that Snakemake deletes it? Kind of `touch(filename)` but in reverse... `delete(filename)`).

And I also need to add to the rule `all` a dependency on the last machine stop, or othervwise that last machine will not be stopped.

This quickly makes the Snake file very complex, as for example:

```py
vm_types = ["small", "medium", "large"]
applications = ["eratostenes", "fibonacci"]
sizes = [100, 500, 1000]
all_files = expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", type=vm_types, app_name=applications, size=sizes)

def perform_experiment(params):
    print("Faking experiment with params", params)
    with open("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data".format(**params), "w") as f:
        f.write("Dummy data")

def start_vm(t):
    print("Starting VM", t)

import os
def stop_vm(t):
    print("Stopping VM", t)
    os.unlink("VM_{}_start.done".format(t))

def previous_vm_type(wildcards):
    if wildcards.type == "small": return []
    return "VM_{}_stop.done".format(vm_types[vm_types.index(wildcards.type)-1])

rule all:
    input: all_files, "VM_{}_stop.done".format(vm_types[-1])

rule perform_experiment:
    input: "VM_{type}_start.done"
    output: "VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data"
    run:
        perform_experiment(wildcards)

rule start_vm:
    input: previous_vm_type
    output: touch("VM_{type}_start.done")
    run:
        start_vm(wildcards.type)

rule stop_vm:
    input: expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", app_name=applications, size=sizes, allow_missing=True)
    output: touch("VM_{type}_stop.done")
    run:
        stop_vm(wildcards.type)
```

This kind of works. It produces the following DAG which looks ok:

[image: DAG]

But nevertheless it has some problems:

1. The approach looks clumsy. It must be a better way!
2. If I want to re-run one of the experiments, say for example `VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data`, how shoud I proceed?

- If I simply delete the file `VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data` and re-run `snakemake`, what happens is that not only that experiment is performed, but **all experiments in that machine**. I guess that it is because all of them depend on `VM_large_start.done`, and that file is refreshed when the machine starts.
- **Even worse** if the deleted file is one of the first VM in the DAG (small machine), then *all* the experiments are re-run, because after running all experiments in "small" machine, the file `VM_small_stop.done` is updated, and that triggers the starting of the next VM type, and so on...
- Putting `ancient()` around the "done" files in the rules has no effect.

### The question

So my "solution" defeates the purpose of using snakemake in the first place. If I want to re-run only one experiment, but this Snakefile will cause to run all of them anyway, better I would have written a sequential python script.

So, what would be a good way to address this problem using Snakemake?

Comment: I might not fully understand what you need, is it feasible to combine `start_vm` `experiment` `stop_vm` into one rule? Then by controlling the number of jobs you can limit how many vms are running in parallel

Comment: The problem is that `experiment` is not a single one, it is a rule which can generates tons of experiments, each one generating a different output file (because of the cartesian product of parameters of each experiment). So, if I combine all in one rule, can I still re-generate a single experiment by simply deleting the output file of that one?

Comment: In other words, I need a solution flexible enough so that if I delete a random subset of the output files, then the rules are able to start the required vm, run in that vm **only the missing experiments**, and then shutdown that vm. This for each vm for which some experiment is missing.

Comment: Okay got it, then combining all into one rule might lead to re-run all experiments if you delete a subset of those. I wonder if there is any command can return the status of vm? I'm thinking about for each experiment, you can first ask if the virtual machine has been started, start the vm if not, otherwise directly run the experiment. `stop_vm` should still be separated out to ensure the vm will be stopped only after all outputs have been generated

Comment: @Jianyu Ok, I understand. But that still does not work. If some experiment results are missing from different VMs (or, for example, if it is the first run of snakemake and all experiments are missing), then snakemake is free to run the experiments in any order, because they do not have input dependencies. This can lead to a first experiment in "small" machine, the second one in "large" machine, the third one again in "small" machine, etc. I want to perform all experiments required in one machine before shutting it down and starting the next one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might need to include some codes to show my idea, this is similar to your posted design. I deleted the `start_vm` rule to let each `perform_experiment` able to start vm by themselves, and if you let `stop_vm` become the dependency for each `perform_experiment` (Also add `ancient` tag to avoid refreshing it leading to re-run all following experiments), it would still first run all experiments on "small" machine, then "medium", then "large".

```
vm_types = ["small", "medium", "large"]
applications = ["eratostenes", "fibonacci"]
sizes = [100, 500, 1000]
all_files = expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", type=vm_types, app_name=applications, size=sizes)

def perform_experiment(params):
    print("Faking experiment with params", params)
    with open("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data".format(**params), "w") as f:
        f.write("Dummy data")

import os
def stop_vm(t):
    print("Stopping VM", t)

def previous_vm_type(wildcards):
    if wildcards.type == "small": return []
    return "VM_{}_stop.done".format(vm_types[vm_types.index(wildcards.type)-1])

rule all:
    input: all_files, "VM_{}_stop.done".format(vm_types[-1])

rule perform_experiment:
    input: lambda wildcards: ancient(previous_vm_type(wildcards))
    output: "VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data"
    run:
        if True:  # check vm status, start vm if it's not running
            print("Starting VM", wildcards.type)
        perform_experiment(wildcards)

rule stop_vm:
    input: expand("VM_{type}_APP_{app_name}_SIZE_{size}.data", app_name=applications, size=sizes, allow_missing=True)
    output: touch("VM_{type}_stop.done")
    run:
        stop_vm(wildcards.type)
```

The dag would be also quite familiar

[image]

What would happen if missing a subset of experiments, `VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data` and `VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data` were deleted

```
$ snakemake -np
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job                   count    min threads    max threads
------------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                       1              1              1
perform_experiment        2              1              1
stop_vm                   2              1              1
total                     5              1              1


[Wed Dec 22 12:50:27 2021]
rule perform_experiment:
    input: VM_small_stop.done
    output: VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data
    jobid: 10
    wildcards: type=medium, app_name=eratostenes, size=1000
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Dec 22 12:50:27 2021]
rule stop_vm:
    input: VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data, VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data, VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_100.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_1000.data
    output: VM_medium_stop.done
    jobid: 15
    wildcards: type=medium
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Dec 22 12:50:27 2021]
rule perform_experiment:
    input: VM_medium_stop.done
    output: VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data
    jobid: 17
    wildcards: type=large, app_name=eratostenes, size=1000
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Dec 22 12:50:27 2021]
rule stop_vm:
    input: VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data, VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data, VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_100.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_1000.data
    output: VM_large_stop.done
    jobid: 21
    wildcards: type=large
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Dec 22 12:50:27 2021]
localrule all:
    input: VM_small_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data, VM_small_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data, VM_small_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data, VM_small_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_100.data, VM_small_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data, VM_small_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_1000.data, VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data, VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data, VM_medium_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_100.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data, VM_medium_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_1000.data, VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_100.data, VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_500.data, VM_large_APP_eratostenes_SIZE_1000.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_100.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data, VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_1000.data, VM_large_stop.done
    jobid: 0
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Job stats:
job                   count    min threads    max threads
------------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                       1              1              1
perform_experiment        2              1              1
stop_vm                   2              1              1
total                     5              1              1

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a good idea but I need to think more about it. Currently it still does not work as it should. Try for example deleting all `VM_small_APP_fibonacci*` files and also `VM_large_APP_fibonacci_SIZE_500.data`. Then, `snakemake` will try to directly run those experiments in any order, because the input dependencies are fulfilled (if `VM_medium_stop.done` is present). This means that it will start the small machine and perform one experiment, but then it could start large machine to perform another experiment without first completing all experiments in the small one.

Comment: If you delete the `*.done` files to avoid this problem, then all experiments in medium machine will be rerun (in order to recreate `VM_medium_stop.done`), and this is not neccessary because "medium" experiments were ok.

Comment: Yes... This is a tricky problem, a workaround might be deleting `VM_medium_stop.done`, then run `snakemake VM_medium_stop.done` to let snakemake only run all "small" experiments, then doing similar things for large ones. But true, this is not perfect